# I am trying to remove the duplicates and return the result. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, arraylist, callback

callbackPractice uniq should return an array to the callback where all duplicates are removed but I am missing something. Please help.

```
function uniq(collection, fn) {
  var uniqCollection = collection.filter(function(item, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) === index;
  });
}

function uniq(collection, fn) {
  var obj = {};
  var uniqArr = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    uniqArr.push(key);
  }
  return fn(uniqArr);
}

var names = ['Tyler', 'Cahlan', 'Ryan', 'Colt', 'Tyler', 'Blaine', 'Cahlan'];
uniq(names, function(uniqArr) {
  console.log('The new names array with all the duplicate items removed is ', uniqArr);
});
```

Comment: Please add the results and/or errors you are receiving...

Comment: You have **two** functions named `uniq`... You are also not using `collection` within the second `uniq()` and instead always iterate over the empty `obj`. .. why two functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your array values into an object and then list all keys - that way you get rid of all duplicates:

```
function uniq(arr, cb){
    var obj = {};
    for (var i in arr) {
      var v = arr[i];
      obj[v] = true;
    }

    var uniqArr = Object.keys(obj);
    (cb || Function.prototype)(uniqArr);
}
```

Comment: This approach is unstable (changes order) and will fail for nonstring elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniq = function(arr, cb) {
      var newArr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          var found = undefined;
          for (var y = 0; y < newArr.length; y++) {
              if (arr[i] === newArr[y]) {
                  found = true;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (found !== true) {
              newArr.push(arr[i]);
          }
      }
      cb(newArr);
  }

    var names = ['Tyler', 'Cahlan', 'Ryan', 'Colt', 'Tyler', 'Blaine', 'Cahlan'];
    uniq(names, function(uniqArr){
      console.log('The new names array with all the duplicate items removed is ', uniqArr);
    });
```